# App crash when ask for gps location (only android)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

#### Issue Description

My app crashes when ask for gps locations (ONLY ANDROID).
The dialog box appears as expected and when I accept or decline the permission, my app crashes with the follow error:

> Tried to use permissions API while not attached to an Activity.

But even with error my app receive the permission, and if I re-open the app works fine.

I think that it is a wix problem because my activity changes with react-native-navigation implementation.

After a lot of reading seems like there is an interface to implement permissions on android, but i can't figure out how to implement on my activity.

#### Steps to Reproduce / Code Snippets / Screenshots

Start app with tabs:

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
        tabs: [
            {
                label: 'Perfil',
                screen: 'tab.profile',
                icon: profileIcon, 
                navigatorStyle: {
                    navBarHidden: true,
                    navBarTextFontSize: 16
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Paquerar',
                screen: 'tab.main',
                icon: heartIcon, 
                navigatorStyle: {
                    navBarHidden: true,
                    navBarTextFontSize: 16
                }
            },
            {
                label: 'Paqueras',
                screen: 'tab.chat',
                icon: paqueraIcon, 
                navigatorStyle: {
                    navBarHidden: true,
                    navBarTextFontSize: 16
                }
            }
        ],
        tabsStyle: { 
            tabBarButtonColor: theme.palette.grayscale[1],
            tabBarSelectedButtonColor: theme.palette.secondary,
            tabBarBackgroundColor: theme.palette.white,
            initialTabIndex: 1,
            tabBarHideShadow: false,
        },
        appStyle: {
            orientation: 'portrait',
            hideBackButtonTitle: true ,
            initialTabIndex: 1,
        }
    });
```

on main tab i ask for permission on componenetDidMount

```
try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                return true;
            }
            else{
               return false;
            }
        }catch (err) {

        }
```

On androidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

     <!-- for Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />`

MainActivity
`package com.beachpaqueraapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;


public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "BeachPaqueraApp";
    }

}
```

On MainApplication

```
package com.beachpaqueraapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.reactnative.ivpusic.imagepicker.PickerPackage;
import com.bitgo.randombytes.RandomBytesPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication implements ReactApplication {


  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(),
            new PickerPackage(),
            new RandomBytesPackage(),
            new LinearGradientPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage()
    );
  }

  @Override
    public boolean isDebug() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

  @Override
    public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
        return getPackages();
    }

    @Override
    public String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

---

#### Environment

- React Native Navigation version: 0.56.0
- React Native version: 1.1.480
- Platform(s) (iOS, Android, or both?): ANDROID
- Device info (Simulator/Device? OS version? Debug/Release?): DEBUG AND RELEASE. 
  SIMULATOR: GENYMOTION NEXUS 6 (ANDROID 8)
  DEVICE: MOTO G4 (ANDROID 8)
  DEVICE: XIAOMI REDMI NOTE 5 (ANDROID 8.1)